# Remove complex pattern from datetime sequence using loops

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

**Background:**

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to follow a certain pattern regarding timestamps.
I would like to first

```
1. Identify the 'Connect' value timestamp
2. Check the action that follows, and check to see if the next action
   is an 'Ended' or 'Attempt' with a less than or equal to 60 second gap
3. If this <= gap of 60 second is present, I wish for the code to Skip these timestamps
   and keep iterating until it comes to the next 'Ended' value, and to record this value.
```

The output pattern should always follow a 'Connect' and 'Ended'

```
We start with:

Connect            4/6/2020 1:11:41 PM

Then look to the next line:

Ended              4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM

Now look to the line that follows:

Attempt            4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM





These two timestamps are less than or equal to 60 seconds, so we keep going    

until we come across an Ended value where these conditions do not apply. 

So the Ended value of 

Ended              4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM    gets recorded.









Action             Time

Connect            4/6/2020 1:11:41 PM

Ended              4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM

Attempt            4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM

Connect            4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM

Ended              4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM

Connect            3/31/2020 11:00:08 AM

Ended              3/31/2020 11:14:54 AM

Ended              3/31/2020 4:17:43 PM
```

As we see below, these rows have been removed since 1:14:20PM and 1:15:20PM are at or less than 60 sec of each other
and 3/31/2020 4:17:43 PM is not the next immediate 'Ended' value that we come across.

```
Ended              4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM

Attempt            4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM

Connect            4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM

Ended              3/31/2020 4:17:43 PM
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Action              Time



Connect             4/6/2020 1:11:41 PM        

Ended               4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM

Connect             3/31/2020 11:00:08 AM

Ended               3/31/2020 11:14:54 AM
```

The output pattern should always follow a 'Connect' and 'Ended'

**Dput:**

```
structure(list(Action = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 

3L), .Label = c("Attempt", "Connect", "Ended"), class =     "factor"), 

 Time = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label =      c("3/31/2020 11:00:08 AM", 

 "3/31/2020 11:14:54 AM", "3/31/2020 4:17:43 PM", "4/6/2020      1:11:41 PM", 

  "4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM", "4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM", "4/6/2020  1:15:21   PM", 

 "4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM"), class = "factor")), class =     "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 

-8L))
```

**This is what I have tried:**

I am thinking that I should use a loop, but not exactly sure on how to construct this. Any help is appreciated.

```
  library(lubridate)

  if (value <= 60) {

   print("") 

   } else {

   Expr2

   }
```

Comment: Between the connect and 'Ended' i.e. 1st and 2nd rows, it is more than 60 secs

Comment: Yes. Once the Connect row is recorded, we look to the 2nd and 3rd rows and see if this is 60 min or less

Comment: for second and third, i get 159 sec and 60 sec

Comment: ok second and third row: Ended              4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM

Attempt            4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM
? let me check

Comment: Hi @Akrun. Not counting the initial 'Connect' row time. I am looking at time dff between the second and third rows:            (2nd row)   1:14:20 PM and (3rd row)  1:15:20 PM. Which is 60 sec, so I would like to skip this and move on until I see the next 'Ended' value and then record this value, which is 
"Ended"              4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM. Is this possible to do with a loop maybe?

Comment: I showed a solution that gives the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could convert the 'Time' to `Datetime` class with `mdy_hms` from `lubridate`, create a grouping variablee based on the occurence of 'Connect' in 'Action', get the difference in 'Time' elements ('Diff'), `filter` out the rows where the difference is less than or equal to 60, then `filter` out the `duplicated` similar element rows of 'Action'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Time1 = mdy_hms(Time)) %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(Action == 'Connect')) %>% 
   mutate(Diff = difftime(Time1, lag(Time1), unit = 'sec'),
     Diff = case_when(any(Diff <=60) ~ 60, TRUE ~ as.numeric(Diff))) %>%
   filter(Action == 'Connect'|Diff >60) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   filter(!duplicated(rleid(Action))) %>% 
   select(Action, Time)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Action  Time                    
#  <fct>   <fct>                   
#1 Connect 4/6/2020      1:11:41 PM
#2 Ended   4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM     
#3 Connect 3/31/2020 11:00:08 AM   
#4 Ended   3/31/2020 11:14:54 AM
```

Comment: I think this moreso matches my desired output! Thank you Akrun. I will try this now

Comment: Filtering on duplicated `rleid(Action)` is slick. Should have thought of that. I'm always hesitant to offer people solutions that use combinations of `dplyr` and `data.table`, but I think I'm just going for it from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach with `dplyr`, `data.table`, and `lubridate`.

First, we calculate the cumulative time that has elapsed in the dataset. Next, we use `cumsum` to break the dataset into connection attempts that are greater than 60 seconds apart. Then, we group by connection attempts and only keep non-Connect events if they occur more than 60 seconds after the first connection attempt. And then to borrow from @akrun's approach, filter on duplicated consecutive actions.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  mutate(Time = mdy_hms(Time)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(Time) %>%
  mutate(CumTime = cumsum(time_length(Time - dplyr::lag(Time, 1L,default = as.integer(min(mdy_hms(df$Time))))))) %>%
  group_by(Action) %>%
  mutate(LastConnect = if_else(Action == "Connect", time_length(CumTime - dplyr::lag(CumTime, 1L, 0)), 0)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(ConnectionInterval = cumsum(Action == "Connect" & LastConnect > 60)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-LastConnect) %>%
  group_by(ConnectionInterval) %>%
  mutate(ConnectCumTime = time_length(Time - dplyr::lag(Time, 1L))) %>% 
  filter(Action == "Connect" | ConnectCumTime > 60 & !duplicated(rleid(Action)))
## A tibble: 6 x 5
## Groups:   ConnectionInterval [3]
#  Action  Time                CumTime ConnectionInterval ConnectCumTime
#  <fct>   <dttm>                <dbl>              <int>          <dbl>
#1 Connect 2020-03-31 11:00:08       0                  0             NA
#2 Ended   2020-03-31 11:14:54     886                  0            886
#3 Connect 2020-04-06 13:11:41  526293                  1             NA
#4 Ended   2020-04-06 13:14:20  526452                  1            159
#5 Connect 2020-04-06 13:15:21  526513                  2             NA
#6 Ended   2020-04-06 14:05:18  529510                  2           2997
```

Comment: thank you!I will try and possibly modify!  I really wish to remove these timestamps Ended              4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM

Attempt            4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM

Connect            4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM  and have this output: 

Connect             4/6/2020 1:11:41 PM        

Ended               4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM but this is a start. Thank you

Comment: yes. Once a 'connect' is established, there has to be an 'ended' value that follows. so we must remove 2020-04-06 13:15:21 (which is another connect value), since we have already established our first connect to be: Connect            4/6/2020 1:11:41 PM

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following. The preceding `Connect 2020-04-06 13:11:41` was terminated by `Ended   2020-04-06 13:14:20` which occurred 159 seconds afterwards. Is the logic that connections should continue if they have been disconnected for 60 seconds or less?

Comment: The logic what I am trying to establish is:  the first connect that you come across, record this time. This is the first start time. Then look to the action that follows, and if the following action from this, has a timediff of 60 sec or less, remove these timestamps and keep iterating until we come across the next Ended value. With the final pattern being that of: Connect and Ended